# Conditional XSL loop over XML.

Tags: xml, loops, xslt

I want to create a loop using XSL through my XML file that only processes the games that have a rating above 5:

```
<game_id id="101">
        <game_name>Minecraft</game_name>
        <game_price currency="€">23.99</game_price>
        <game_type type="Sandbox" />
        <game_art>minecraft.jpg</game_art>
        <game_platform>
            <platform platform="XboxOne">XboxOne</platform>
            <platform platform="Ps4">Ps4</platform>
            <platform platform="PC">PC</platform>
            <platform platform="Mac">Mac</platform>
        </game_platform>
        <game_desc>Simple block based game</game_desc>
        <game_dev>Mojang</game_dev>
        <game_rating rating="9">5/10 </game_rating>
        <game_review>
            <para para="1">The game involves players creating and destroying various types of blocks in a three dimensional environment. 
                        The player takes an avatar that can destroy or create blocks, forming fantastic structures, 
                        creations and artwork across the various multiplayer servers in multiple game modes
                        </para>
            <para para="x"></para>
            <para para="x"></para>
        </game_review>
    </game_id>
```

I've been trying to create the loop but my attempt has failed:

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="game_id/game_rating =  '5'">
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="game_name"></xsl:value-of></h1>
            <hr />
                <img> <xsl:attribute name="src"> <xsl:value-of select="game_art"/></xsl:attribute></img>

                    <p><strong>Price:</strong> <xsl:value-of select="game_price"></xsl:value-of></p>

                    <xsl:for-each select="game_platform/platform">
                    <p><strong>Platform:</strong> <xsl:value-of select="node()"></xsl:value-of></p>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                    <p><strong>Game Desc: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="game_desc"></xsl:value-of></p>

                    <p><strong>Game Dev: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="game_dev"></xsl:value-of></p>

                    <p><strong>Game Rating: </strong> <xsl:value-of select="game_rating"></xsl:value-of></p>

                    <h4>Game Reveiw</h4>
                    <xsl:for-each select="game_review/para"> 
                        <p><xsl:value-of select="node()"></xsl:value-of></p>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>

            </xsl:choose>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A loop is not necessary (nor desirable): use a **predicate** instead.

Comment: I do not understand your XML: `<game_rating rating="9">5/10 </game_rating>` - is the rating `9` or `5/10`?

Comment: If you want to loop, use the FOR statement available in BASIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you wouldn't need a loop here, but you use template matching. Assuming you had multiple **game_id** elements, and were positioned on the parent element of them, you could just do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="game_id[number(game_rating/@rating) > 5]" />
```

Then, you would have a template that matches **game_id**

```
<xsl:template match="game_id">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="game_name"></xsl:value-of></h1>
```

For example, given this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="game_id[number(game_rating/@rating) > 5]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="game_id">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="game_name" /></h1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<games>
    <game_id id="101">
        <game_name>Minecraft</game_name>
        <game_rating rating="9">9/10</game_rating>
    </game_id>
    <game_id id="102">
        <game_name>Goat Simulator</game_name>
        <game_rating rating="4">4/10</game_rating>
    </game_id>
</games>
```

Then the following is output

```
 <h1>Minecraft</h1>
```

Alternatively, depending on the actual structure of your XML, you could allow XSLT's built-in template to do some select the nodes, and have an extra template to exclude games with low ratings. The following would also give the same output in this case.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="game_id[number(game_rating/@rating) &lt;= 5]" />

    <xsl:template match="game_id">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="game_name" /></h1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, This was starting to really wreck my head.

Comment: Also...How did you know i had used Goat Simulator...Its such an addictive game :)